# Django REST Framework - optimizing nested serialization of a queryset

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a model and serializer like this:

models.py

```
class CalendarEvent(BaseMixin):
    title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class CalendarEventReminder(BaseMixin):
     event = models.ForeignKey(CalendarEvent, related_name = 'reminders')
     minutes = models.CharField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'calendar_event_reminder'

def __str__(self):
    return self.minutes
```

serializer.py

```
class CalendarEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reminders = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CalendarEvent
        fields = ('title', 'reminders')
```

In my view, I do the following:

```
def test(request):
    #...
    event = CalendarEvent.objects.filter(id__in = [930, 935])
    serializer = CalendarEventSerializer(event, many = True)
    print (serializer.data)
    #...
```

When I open the Debug Toolbar, I see that the database hits reminders table twice for each of the calendar events.

[image]

The question is, how this behavior could be optimized.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight-forward way would be prefetching the CalendarEventReminders of the CalendarEvents in your view:

```
# views.py
def get(request):
    event = CalendarEvent.objects.filter(id__in = [930, 935]) \
                                 .prefetch_related('reminders')
    # ...
```

This will prefetch all CalendarEventReminders while getting the CalendarEvents.

Note that this will not trigger a sql join like `select_related()` would do. We can't use `select_related()` in this case because we're following the relation backwards. :)

Check out the [Django Docs regarding `prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Comment: Well, I know about `prefetch_related`. The question was, how can I do it via nested serializers. Are they intented to only serialize objects and not querysets ?

Comment: Yes, serializers only serialize objects. The handling of your queryset is done in your view. Your queries as seen in the debug toolbar are triggered by simple `__getitem__` calls to your queryset, that's why `prefetch_related` will eliminate those queries or rather, fetch them all at once at the beginning.